# Invoke Google Earth address search from a hyperlinked command in a table cell

Tags: arcmap, google-earth-engine, google-earth

I would like to be able to launch a Google Earth search in Windows by clicking a table cell that contains a street address (plus town and US state abbreviation). For example, I have a table in ArcMap that has a field populated with Google Earth web search urls like this:

`https://earth.google.com/web/search/123 Main St, Anytown, NY`

The corresponding feature layer can be set so that when you click a feature with the info tool, you can then click the search attribute and launch a Google Earth web search (assuming Chrome is set as the default browser).

But what I would like to find is a way to populate that field instead with a command such that when I click the cell in the table itself, it invokes a Google Earth desktop search on the given address. This because I want to see the search location in the context of kml data I have loaded in Earth on my computer.
I get the impression from [this Google Earth Engine site](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/command_line) that this might be possible, but there I'm straying outside my competencies.

Comment: What coding skills do you have?  More than likely you will need to throw some code together, either in python or .Net.

Comment: Grazie, Barbarossa. My skills are no match for the Dark Side, sadly. I know enough Python to get into trouble, but not out. I was hoping there might be some way to hyperlink a string something like C:\<file path>\googleearth.exe\<search string>. But from what Christiaan writes below, it appears not.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the similar name, "Earth Engine" is a very different tool (mostly for analysis of satellite imagery and other GIS operations), so probably not relevant for looking up addresses in "Google Earth".

As you found, URLs can be constructed for search queries in the new Google Earth for web (v9). Unfortunately there is not a similarly easy way to trigger a search in Google Earth Pro (v7). There used to be a "com api" for Earth Pro, which would let you do similar things, but that is no longer supported, so there's not an easy way to trigger actions from outside the app.

Two ideas that come to mind... first, you could export your data from ArcMap to a KML file, which you could load in Earth Pro alongside your other datasets. Of course, if you're looking to rely on Earth's search results to find places from addresses, then maybe you don't have location coordinates yet, which makes creating a KML difficult.  Maybe find a geocoding service, and look up the addresses, add the coordinates in ArcGIS, and generate a KML that way?

The other idea, if all you need is to view your addresses one at a time along with some KML data, is to load that KML data into Earth for web.  KML support in Earth v9 is still experimental, but you can enable it at the bottom of the settings menu, and then use the My Places panel to bring in KMLs. Earth for web supports most basic KML, but not yet some of the advanced KML features that Earth Pro supports. Once you save your KML(s) in the Places panel, then use the Earth + search URLs you already have to load Earth with the KML and your search results visible.

Comment: Our organization reverted back to GE 7.0.2.8415 in order to make use of the COM API in our ArcMap addins.

Comment: Thanks for your observations, Christiaan! I did make a kml of the geocoded addresses, but the problem is that I can't edit the feature attributes in Earth (as far as I know). My end product has to be a table where I've toggled an attribute, then I submit the table to have those edits integrated into the mother database.

Comment: I'm making the edits in ArcMap, and I often copy the street address from the table into an Earth search to view the address in the context of parcel polygons. What I was hoping to do is cut down on the mouse clicks. I could do the whole thing in Arc with an imagery basemap, but I think it'd be too slow with the imagery loaded.